# MySQL errno: 24 - Too many open files

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, percona

MySQL 5.7.36-39-log Percona Server

Have recently received: errno: 24 - Too many open files

I have observed that status open_files is continually increasing. This is new behavior as the number of open_files used to fluctuate up and down on a daily basis, but it did not continually increase.

Very concerned as it would seem that MySQL is not releasing its hold on files. I will eventually hit mysql/system limits. Not sure what exactly is going on here.

Comment: How much RAM?  What are the values of `max_connections`, `table_open_cache`?  Or simply provide `STATUS` and `VARIABLES`:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Comment: RAM: 400GB, max_connections: 3000, table_open_cache: 1010

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to `Open_files` (with a capital `O`).

Some operating systems set `open_files_limit` to 1024.  This is unreasonably low for MySQL.  See `ulimit` for how to increase it, then restart MySQL.

Don't worry about the STATUS value growing, it seems to have no impact on performance.

Comment: Thanks. We have already increased ulimit. This is new behavior and so we are interested in why this is happening and if this is not ideal behavior a solution to stop the continual growth.

Comment: I would expect, _but don't know for sure_, that "Open_xx" is the number of currently open xx's; "Opened_xx" is is the total number of "opens" -- counting some xx's multiple times in case they were closed and reopened.  "yy_cache" (such as `table_open_cache`) should be a "cache" -- when it runs out of room, something is bumped out to make room.